# This challenge is about recursion (Robbers' thread)

Tags: code-golf, sequence, cops-and-robbers

## Robbers thread

In this thread, your task is to find a non-recursive solution which produces the same integer series of a submission not marked as 'safe' in the **[Cops' thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/157396/this-challenge-is-about-recursion-cops-thread/)**.

## Challenge synopsis

In many languages, recursive functions can significantly simplify a programming task. However, the syntax overhead for a proper recursion may limits its usability in code-golf.

The **cops** will create a program or function taking a single integer `n`, which will generate the first `n` entries of an integer series, **using only recursion.**<sup>1</sup>.

The **robbers** will try to find a **shorter** program or function in the same language, generating the same integer series, **using no recursion**<sup>2</sup>.

If the cops' submission is not cracked within ten days (240 hours), the cop will prove it was in fact possible to have a shorter non-recursive approach by revealing their own solution. They may then mark their submission as **safe**.

The winner of the cops challenge will be the shortest (according to [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)) recursion-based submission marked safe.

**The winner of the robbers challenge will be the robber who cracked the most solutions.**

<sup>1: It only needs to be recursive in syntax; you don't need to worry about for example tail call optimization.</sup>

<sup>2: Again, non-recursive in syntax; so you can't post a recursive solution and claim its compiled to a loop thanks to tail call optimization.</sup>

## Requirements

Each submission will take a single integer `n` (zero- or one-based). The submission will then output or return the first `n` entries of the same integer series as the cops' entry. The input and output method may differ between the recursive and non-recursive approach.

Your robbers' entry must be **strictly shorter** in byte-count than the recursive solution. It must work for at least the same `n`, or up to `n=2^15-1`, whichever is smaller.

## Recursion

For the sake of this challenge, recursion is defined as creating the desired sequence using a **function** (or function-like construct) that **calls itself** (or calls a sequence of functions that ends up calling itself). The recursion depth should go to infinity as `n` goes to infinity. The non-recursive approach is anything that is **not** recursive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74105/discussion-between-sanchises-and-l4m2).

Comment: Now make a mirror question

Answer (score 3):

## [Octave](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157397/31516), by Sanchises 27 bytes

There are so many, many ways to do this in a loopy-way. For instance this one, if an explicit loop is needed:

```matlab
for i=1:input('')disp(i)end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f8/Lb9IIdPW0Cozr6C0RENdXVMnJbO4QCNTUyc1L@X/f0MDAA)

Or, if you want to create a vector (I haven't golfed this terribly well, since using a loop like this is kinda pointless):

```matlab
x=0;for i=1:input(''),x(i)=i;end,x
```

Or 7 bytes if it's OK to not use a loop at all:

```matlab
@(n)1:n
```

Answer (score 3):

### [Python 3, 75 bytes by Bubbler](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157494/20260)

**[Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes**

```python
lambda n:[k for k in range(1,2**n)if 60**k%k<1][:n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjpbIS2/SCFbITNPoSgxLz1Vw1DHSEsrTzMzTcHMQEsrWzXbxjA22iov9j9IXSaSOgNNKy6FgqLMvBKNNI1MTc3/AA)

Tests for 5-smoothness of `k` with `60**k%k<1`.

Comment: You may have missed my comment, but I consider using the Y combinator a recursive solution.

Comment: The robber's solution should be shorter than the cop's, so Y combinator doesn't work in general anyway.

Comment: @Sanchises I only saw your comment after posting this. I think this is non-recursive by all definitions I've seen, so I think you should define what it means more cleanly. But I had missed that the new solution needs to be shorter, so the Y combinator method shouldn't work in general.

Comment: But the second solution looks good though the current upper bound doesn't work at `n>=1000` or so; you can throw in `2**n` for correctness, then I'll mark my solution as cracked.

Comment: @xnor Interesting, I would've never considered that non-recursive. Any ideas for a good definition which really encompasses the "nested function"-ness that is typical of recursion, whether true recursion or via a helper function?

Comment: @Sanchises Well, what makes sense in my head would allow the Y combinator trick, so I don't know how helpful I can be for you here. I would say that a function can do whatever it wants with its arguments, but when its definition mentions another function, we take note of that. And if a function references itself or there's a cycle in the graph of mentions, that's recursive. So, a function can't hide using helper functions inside it. But the Y combinator trick is special in that there's really no cycle in the graph.

Comment: @xnor And yet (in your first version), `h` keeps calling `h` (well, it's calling `g`, which just so happens to be `h`). So there's no cycle in definitions, but there's definitely a cycle going on during execution. And I would consider this a very different cycle than a loop; I would much rather implement mergesort with a Y combinator than with just do-while constructs. So, perhaps the ability to branch into self-similar loops sets my idea of recursion apart from nonrecursion?

Comment: @xnor Looking at [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93526/what-is-a-y-combinator), the Y combinator is described as *allows you to implement recursion* (first answer), *it generalizes recursion* (second answer), *[it] calculates [...] recursively* (third answer). So perhaps it's fair to call using a Y combinator recursive after all? Or are all these answers wrong?

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org/), by [user71546](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157406/76323), <s>74</s> 72 Bytes

```
n=>{for(i=s=0;j=i++<n;console.log(s))for(x=i;j++<i;)for(;x%j<1;x/=j)s++}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Gol><> by Jo King](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157662/34718), 12 bytes iterative

```
I:FL:R0|rRN;
```

[**Try it online**](https://tio.run/##S8/PScsszvj/39PKzccqyKCmKMjP@v9/IyMA)

Makes good use of `R`, the repeat command. Once I thought of this method, I knew it would be shorter than trying to use a for loop within a while loop.

**Explanation:**

```
I:              Input and duplicate (will be used at the end to print). 
  F             For loop input times. 
   L:           Push and duplicate loop counter (leaving one on the stack). 
     R0         Pop counter and push that many zeros. 
       |        End of loop. 
        r       Reverse the stack. 
         RN;    Print input times and halt.
```

[List of language commands](https://github.com/Sp3000/Golfish/blob/master/src/doc.txt) (`D` debug is useful for understanding what is going on)

<sub><sub><sub><sub><sub>Golfish</sub></sub></sub></sub></sub>

Answer (score 1):

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/158075/76323, 78 Bytes

```
def A(n):
 x=[1]*n
 for i in range(2,n):x[i]=x[x[i-1]-1]+x[i-x[i-1]]
 return x
```

Answer (score 0):

## https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157397/76323, 7 bytes assuming it's not recursive

```
@(n)1:n
```

or if use for,

```
function o=f(n);for i=1:n;disp(i);end;end;
```

Answer (score 0):

## [COM function](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157428/55934), by l4m2, 11 bytes iterative

```
0: 31 C0    xor ax, ax
2: BF 01 00 mov di, 1
5: 01 F8    add ax, di
7: AB       stosw
8: E2 FB    loop 5
A: C3       ret
```

Input CX, output [ES:1] ~ [ES:2*CX] (inclusive)

Comment: Is backward array allowed?

Comment: @l4m2 I don't see a reason for it to be not allowed, but if you insist, `std` is one byte.

Comment: Asked about that on meta

Comment: meta leads to Default for Code Golf: Input/Output methods where only https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13262/76323 matters

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), by jmarkmurphy, 22 bytes iterative

```forth
: | 0 do i 1+ . loop ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WynUKBgopOQrZCoYaivoKeTk5xcoWP83Vaj5DwA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Python 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157757/78841) by PunPun1000, 59 bytes iterative

```
def f(x):
 l=[1]
 while x>0:l+=[sum(l[-2:])];x-=1
 return l
```

I tried my hardest to do a closed-form one-liner, but I only got as low as the original submission.

Comment: Couldn’t you just do `while x:` rather than `x>0`?

Comment: @JoKing Probably. I was basing this off the original code, and I wasn't sure what some of the intent was.

Answer (score 0):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/157811/76323), 45 bytes

```javascript
x=>[...Array(x)].map(_=>h=h&1?3*h+1:h/2,h=14)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFtDoIwDADQ25jWacn8@CMU4zmIIQsyW4OUDGLw9OO9T/iFuUs6LcfRXn3OkVeuGyJ6pBT@sOKTvmGClmth2fn7eS/O36Q4HYT9BXO0BMq@1IqvpTqHnY2zDT0N9oYIipg3)